# How to find a class with prefix and append to an element?

Tags: jquery, class, find

I have several articles on a blog and I need to set each post's category from the "p_" class.

```
<article class="some-class p_category-name post">
    This is the category: <span id="category"></span>
</article>
```

This is my code, but doesn't work (I'm not so good in jQ):

```
var category = $("article.post").find("div[class^='p_'], div[class*=' p_']");
$("#category").text(category);
```

Edit: it has a chance that not every post has a "p_" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
$('article.post > span.category').text(function () {
    return $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\bp_(.*?)[\s|$]/)[1]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3aWpJ/)

I changed the markup to use class `category` for the span so that there can be multiple articles in the page

```
<article class="some-class p_category-name post">
    This is the category: <span class="category"></span>
</article>
```

Comment: This is almost good, but as you see, the category's name is "category-name" and your script only wrote "category".

Comment: sorry, my bad, we use "r_" and not "p_" and I just noticed that. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Sir [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) has a great answer

just a penny to his answer to make it work as OP wants.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3aWpJ/5/)

```
$('article.post > span.category').text(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\bp_(.*?)*\s\b/)[0]).replace('p_', '');
})
```

Comment: I only get `Object[]` back in console.

Comment: yeah what do you want explain ? and do you have category for all ?

Comment: Yes, every post has a category, and only 1.

Comment: sorry, my bad, we use "r_" and not "p_" and I just noticed that. I accept Arun's answer cause he gave the main idea + he removes the prefix :)

Comment: @Stefanie fixed the issue. yeah Arun's answer is better. :)